# Find the number of ways in which India can win the series of 11 matches (If no match is drawn and all matches played).

Tags: combinations

**Q)** Find the number of ways in which India can win the series
of 11 matches (If no match is drawn and all matches played).

My answer:${11\choose 6}\cdot2^5$

Answer provided in book:$2^{10}$

**My approach**
For winning a series India must win at least 6 matches of the 11 played which can be done in $11\choose6$ ways and the other 5 matches can be either won or lost which can be done in $2^5$ ways.

*Therefore* total no. of ways India can win the match is ${11\choose 6}\cdot2^5$.

'''Where am I getting wrong ?'''

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in`$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Comment: Note that the number of ways India can win is the same as the number of ways the other team (Australia?) can win, so the answer $2^{10}$ is immediate. To see what you're doing wrong, look at a smaller example, like five matches, where you can write everything out and see where you're double-counting.

Comment: Just as you mentioned, India needs to win 'at least' 6 matches of the series. So where are the other possibilities, like if India wins 7 or more games?

Answer (score 2):

The mistake in your calculation is that you are double counting.  Suppose India wins $7$ matches.  You have counted that outcome $7$ times, because there are $7$ ways to choose $6$ of the winning games.  The proper calculations is to note that India can win exactly $6$ matches or exactly $7$, etc. so that the total is
$$\binom{11}6+\binom{11}7+\binom{11}8+\binom{11}9+\binom{11}{10}+\binom{11}{11}\tag1$$

Since $\binom{11}{k}=\binom{11}{11-k},\ k=0,1,\dots,11$, we see that $(1)$ is equal to $$\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{11}\binom{11}k=\frac{2^{11}}2=2^{10}$$

Comment: Thanks @trueblueanil

Comment: Oh, just a stray typo !